# Proper Linq Query for objects with many to many relation ship generated with code first entity framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

I have two object models, Product & Product Category

```
public class Product{
    int Id {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<ProductCategory> Categories { get; set; }
}

public class ProductCategory{
    int Id {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

which have a many to many relationship that is generated using the code first method in  entity framework.

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().
            HasMany(p => p.Categories).
            WithMany(c => c.Products)
            .Map(m =>
            {
                m.MapLeftKey("ProductId");
                m.MapRightKey("CategoryId");
                m.ToTable("ProductJoinProductCategory");
            });
```

When I query

```
var productCategory = await db.ProductCategories.FirstOrDefaultAsync(category => category.Id == Id);
```

The Products collection returns empty, even though my database is populated with several products in the ProductJoinProductCategory table.

Currently I am doing the following to populate the product collection

```
  var productCategory = await db.ProductCategories.FirstOrDefaultAsync(category => category.Id == Id);
  productCategory.Products = db.Products.Where(x => x.Categories.Any(p => p.Id == Id)).ToList();
```

Is there a way to accomplish this in a single query? The product object will eventually have multiple many many to many relationships with other objects and I would like to find out the proper way to query an object and return it with all its many-many field collections fully populated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following should work:

```
var productCategory = await db.ProductCategories.Include(p => p.Categories.Select(c => c.Products)).FirstOrDefaultAsync(category => category.Id == Id);
```